# django auto generate and create Models.py file and other files

Tags: python-3.x, django

In django using python `manage.py startapp appname` it generate folder with appname etc.... or when using `admin-panel startproject projectname` it generate folder with projectname and all its parameters  classes
how this work ???

Comment: You can check [django](https://github.com/django/django) source code for information

Comment: @AnkitTiwari i did but i could not find any hint , bcs my python level is not that good

Comment: Hello @abdo to get information about waht you've asked for that you've to search for it because it's divided into various parts of file some of are here for creating apps & models I guess this file is responsible [models](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/apps/config.py)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code of the django core management commands
(Management commands is what you call like 'manage.py command'):

https://github.com/django/django/tree/main/django/core/management/commands